# DTN weather widget not showing up on page?

Tags: javascript, html, weather

I am attempting to use DTN's weather widget to hopefully create a widget on top of background image. However, I have not been able to at least get the widget to show up. Below is my code:

```
<HTML>  
    <head>
            <script src="https://content-services.dtn.com/ui-widgets/local-weather-widget/local-weather-widget-1.0-latest.js">

            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is a weather widget:</p>
        <div class="widget" id="local-weather-widget" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 10px;">
            </div>


            <script>


                window.dtn.localWeather.createLocalWeatherWidget({


                "apiKey": "oViXqthDGFNVw3IvAsnKrFG1AcfPyA6b",
                "container": "#local-weather-widget",
                "units": "Imperial",
                "defaultLocation": {
                "postalCode": "68033"
                },
                "stations": [
                {
                    "id": "KTPH",
                    "displayName": "Station 1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "KSNA",
                    "displayName": "Station 2"
                }
                ],
                "showStationsSelect": true,
                "showPostalCodeInput": true,
                "showForecast": true,
                "showCurrentConditions": true,
                "showWeatherDetails": true,
                "callbacks": {
                "onStationChange": "",
                "onPostalCodeChange": "",
                "onWeatherChange": ""
                }


                });
            </script>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

According to the website where I got the start up information from I need API Key, I'm using the test API Key they have given on the website.

Comment: Have you tried using your own API key, like the instructions tell you?  Have you gleaned anything useful from your browser's developer console?

Comment: Unfortunately, when I contacted them for the API Key, their email didn't work, is there another way I can obtain one?

Comment: I get a 403 on some the API Keys, and the following message: "The key is valid, but not authorized for the domain. Please contact DTN customer support."

Comment: that message tells you everything you need to know.  You're attempting to use an API key that is not associated w/the domain from which you're requesting the widget.  Think about this: if your API key is associated with your domain example.com, and then someone extracts that API key and starts using it from anotherdomain.com, do you think that should be allowed?  Or do you think the person making requests from anotherdomain.com should be blocked from using your API key to do it? In your sample code, you're hijacking someone else's API key. So it's not allowed.

Comment: I found the solution, I needed to contact the affiliate to authorize my domain and they provided API keys as well.

Answer (score 0):

To use the widget you must have authorization for the domain (sampleDomain.com) and retrieve API Keys from the affiliate. These can be obtain by contacting the affiliate or organization providing the API or widget.